# Trying to find all <a> elements without a *specific* class

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying web scraping for the first time and I'm using BeautifulSoup to gather bits of information from a website. I'm trying to get all the  elements which has one class but not another. For example:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """
<a class="something">Information I want</a>
<a class="something somethingelse">Information I don't want</a>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
```

In this example, I want to get all the  elements with the `something` class. However, when finding all elements containing that class I also get the element containing the `somethingelse` class, and I do **not** want these.

The code I'm using to get it is:

```py
results = soup.find_all("a", {"class": "something"})
```

Any help is appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work fine:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
text = '''<a class="something">Information I want</a>
<a class="something somethingelse">Information I don't want</a>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(text, 'html.parser')
r1 = soup.find_all("a", {"class": "something"})
r2 = soup.find_all("a", {"class": "somethingelse"})
for item in r2:
    if item in r1:
        r1.remove(item)
print(r1)
```

**Output**

```
[<a class="something">Information I want</a>]
```

For extracting the text present in the tags, just add this lines:

```
for item in r1:
    print(item.text)
```

**Output**

```
Information I want
```

Comment: The end goal is to abstract the text `Information I want`. However, I'm not sure of how to do it with BeautifulSoup, and am instead using `.split()` . Is using split fine or is there a more efficient way to do it through BeautifulSoup?

Comment: @xupaii Added some more code, it will help

Comment: @xupaii If you found this answer helpful, consider validating the answer as correct!

Answer (score 2):

For this task, you can find elements by lambda function, for example:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


html_doc = """<a class="something">Information I want</a>
<a class="something somethingelse">Information I don't want</a>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, "html.parser")

a = soup.find(
    lambda tag: tag.name == "a" and tag.get("class", []) == ["something"]
)
print(a)
```

Prints:

```html
<a class="something">Information I want</a>
```

---

Or: specify "class" as a `list`:

```
a = soup.find("a", {"class": ["something"]})    
print(a)
```

Prints:

```html
<a class="something">Information I want</a>
```

---

EDIT:

For filtering `type-icon type-X`:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


html_doc = """
<a class="type-icon type-1">Information I want 1</a>
<a class="type-icon type-1 type-cell type-abbr">Information I don't want</a>
<a class="type-icon type-2">Information I want 2</a>
<a class="type-icon type-2 type-cell type-abbr">Information I don't want</a>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, "html.parser")


my_types = ["type-icon", "type-1", "type-2"]


def my_filter(tag):
    if tag.name != "a":
        return False
    c = tag.get("class", [])
    return "type-icon" in c and not set(c).difference(my_types)


a = soup.find_all(my_filter)
print(a)
```

Prints:

```
[<a class="type-icon type-1">Information I want 1</a>, <a class="type-icon type-2">Information I want 2</a>]
```

Or extract tags you don't want first:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, "html.parser")

# extract tags I don't want:
for t in soup.select(".type-cell.type-abbr"):
    t.extract()

print(soup.select(".type-icon.type-1, .type-icon.type-2"))
```

Prints:

```
[<a class="type-icon type-1">Information I want 1</a>, <a class="type-icon type-2">Information I want 2</a>]
```

Comment: The class I am looking for is more like: `type-icon type-X`, and the ones I'm trying to avoid are `type-icon type-X type-cell type-abbr`. However, `X` can be one of 18 values. How would I adjust the code to work for this?

Comment: @xupaii I updated my answer. You can alter your filtering function, or just `extract()` all tags you don't need from your soup first, then select your tags.